# asp .net mvc2. how to create a clone like tadalist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently learning asp.net MVC2. I was trying to do a simple project similar to tadalist.com

Could you please guide me to some articles on how to create the dynamic textboxes and how to capture the user  input for persistance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help. Try the demo.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/12/22/editing-a-variable-length-list-of-items-in-aspnet-mvc/